I'm using onesignal api to send notifications and everything works well with php+curl
I'm now trying to attach an image to chrome users without success. It work using the onesignal backoffice but not using the api.
{
    "app_id": "aaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeee",
    "headings": {
        "en": "Hello"
    },
    "title": {
        "en": "Everyone"
    },
    "data": {
        "en": "Good night"
    },
    "included_segments": ["All"],
    "chrome_big_picture": "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/abstract-autumn-beauty-multi-colored-leaf-vein-pattern-generated-by-ai_188544-9871.jpg?t=st=1714979323~exp=1714982923~hmac=118454a049ef52fc38dc8a258c6f1f31597f69f4cf3cb5ef12fb209d4e4402a6&w",
    "content_available": true,
    "contents": {
        "en": "Hello everyone"
    }
}


The URL you used there does not return an image for me, but only a text error message saying "Invalid w parameter (5000)."

Thank you for Reply,  could you please explain what i need to do for resolving this issue

this json data is for integrating onesignal push notification api

I'd first of all try this with an image URL that you are in full control of - so that you can make sure, that no additional access restrictions apply. Using an image from some free service, might come with restrictions you don't even know about.

You haven't shared any PHP code, nor any MySQL queries. Are you sure these two techniques are even related if you write that "everything works well"? Are you facing any error message that you could share?

atleast url should be display in onesignal dashbord

iam beginer  level please explain in detailed

What exactly should be explained? If you have any question about your code, share that code, along with any error message or other description of what exactly is not working yet

Try without the w at the end of the image link like this:
{
    "app_id": "aaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeee",
    "headings": {
        "en": "Hello"
    },
    "title": {
        "en": "Everyone"
    },
    "data": {
        "en": "Good night"
    },
    "included_segments": ["All"],
    "chrome_big_picture": "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/abstract-autumn-beauty-multi-colored-leaf-vein-pattern-generated-by-ai_188544-9871.jpg?t=st=1714979323~exp=1714982923~hmac=118454a049ef52fc38dc8a258c6f1f31597f69f4cf3cb5ef12fb209d4e4402a6",
    "content_available": true,
    "contents": {
        "en": "Hello everyone"
    }
}


still it's not working
